# Add New inbox tab in customer my dashboard in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to create a new tab in customer my dashboard using magento 2 called mymail(inbox). Any email, admin send to customer id then store also in this tab based on Gmail Inbox. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I have followed your blog @http://gworks.mobi/blog/2016/05/17/mymail-custom-tab-in-customer-dashboard/ and it helped me thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 8):

Add below files into your custom module

Ex:-Namespace:- Mytest Modulename : Myemail;

1. Create customer_account.xml into Mytest/Myemail/view/frontend/layout

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
               <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-myemail">
                   <arguments>
                       <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">myemail/customer</argument>
                       <argument name="label" xsi:type="string"> MyEmail</argument>
                   </arguments>
               </block>
           </referenceBlock>
       </body>
    </page>
   ```
2. Create myemail_customer_index.xml into Mytest/Myemail/view/frontend/layout

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <update handle="customer_account"/>
       <body>
           <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
               <action method="setPageTitle">
                   <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">MyEmail</argument>
               </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my_email" template="Mytest_Myemail::test.phtml">
                </block>
           </referenceContainer>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
3. Create Index.php into Mytest/Myemail/Controller/Customer

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Mytest\Myemail\Controller\Customer;

   class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    public function execute() {

       $this->_view->loadLayout();

       $this->_view->renderLayout();
     }

   }
   ```
4. Create test.phtml into Mytest/Myemail/view/frontend/templates

   ```
   <?php // Add some code ?>
   ```
5. Put routes.xml into folder Mytest/Myemail/etc/frontend with the following inside:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?> 
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc‌​/routes.xsd">
       <router id="standard"> 
           <route id="myemail" frontName="myemail"> 
               <module name="Mytest_Myemail" /> 
           </route> 
       </router> 
   </config>
   ```

Comment: You have to create also routes.xml otherwise your controller will be 404 error.:)

Comment: @user3913802, Can you please let me know how I can create the routes.xml file for same module?

Comment: Put `routes.xml` into folder `Mytest/Myemail/etc/frontend` with the following inside:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="myemail" frontName="myemail">
            <module name="Mytest_Myemail" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>`