# Magento 2 add new tab in customer dashboard frontend

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I am trying to create new tab in customer dashboard.I have added customer_account.xml in my module(Singh/Module1)layout

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-about-me">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">aboutme/customer/index</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">About Me</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

**frontName :** aboutme;

**My Controller directory structure:** Singh/Module1/Controller/Customer/Index.php.

I have created **aboutme_customer_index.xml** also

```
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" template="account/link/back.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Below is the index.php

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action //implements AboutmeInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Customer order history
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('About Me'));

    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.account.link.back');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    }
    return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Below is my route file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="aboutme" frontName="aboutme">
        <module name="Singh_Module1" />
    </route>
</router>
```

My new tab is coming in Customer account dashboard but it always redirect to 404 not found error.

Comment: plz show your index.php controller file and also routes.xml file to check more

Comment: I tried by applying die in execute() method; but the control is not coming to there

Comment: please refer this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108421/add-new-inbox-tab-in-customer-my-dashboard-in-magento-2 Hope help you

Comment: can you show folder tree structure of your module ?

Comment: I got the output. I tried by myself and got the output. Thank you all

Comment: my question is: index.php or Index.php ?? is it a problem ??

Comment: Use Correct Module name in routes.xml to avoid 404 errors.

Comment: Please let me know location of add new module for add new tab on customer dashboard. Right now i have placed inside of app/code and it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace the your controller code with this:

```
namespace Singh\Module1\Controller\Customer;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action //implements AboutmeInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Customer order history
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('About Me'));

    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.account.link.back');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    }
    return $resultPage;
    }
}
```